# Oracle + Select2 - How can i load for e.g 10 rows from database. ASP .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, oracle, jquery-select2

I have working with Oracle database and Select2(jquery selectboxes). I have a table in database that contains ~500 000 records. I want to get for e.g first 10-20 records from this table and put it into Select2 dropdownlist. Then when user start typying into SearchBox(Select2) the query will change to get only 10-20 records that matched with the typed values. Is that possible? Or maybe you have another solution how to handle this problem? I think the dropdownlist will be the best.

Thanks for your reply.

So far I've tried this:

```js
$('#ddlDost').select2({
 url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/mypage.aspx/getResults") %>',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    params: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    quietMillis: 100,
    data: function (term, page) {
        return JSON.stringify({ q: term, page_limit: 10 });
    },
    results: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return { results: data };
    }
});
```

and code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public static String getResults(String q, String page_limit)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connString = "myConnString";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENTITY as id ,NAME as text from Supp";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(dc.ColumnName, dr[dc]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

It looks like this WebMethod is not started. When i set 'debugger;' into js code it looks like the results doesnt started too. I dont have nothing in console from "console.log(data)".

Someone could help me with this problem?

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: Hmm. The answer is: I've tried nothing. I just want to ask if it is possible to do it, and maybe someone could guide me how to